# I've got a function that auto creates taxonomy terms - Can it auto delete them as well?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions

I've got this inside my functions.php file.

```
    function add_product_category_automatically($post_ID) {
global $wpdb;
if(!has_term('','product_relation',$post_ID)){
    $cat = get_the_title($post_ID);
    wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, $cat, 'product_relation');
}
}
add_action('publish_product', 'add_product_category_automatically');
```

It creates terms in the 'product_relation' taxonomy when a product is published. Is it possible to also have the terms automatically deleted when the product is moved to the trash?

Thanks

Comment: There's only one custom taxonomy, called 'product_relation', which is registered somewhere else using `register_taxonomy()`. What this code is creating is custom terms in that taxonomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some confusion in the original question with the terminology i used. I didn't find a way to do what i was after but it's to late for me to do it now.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of deleting the taxonomy, wouldn't you rather simply hide it from queries (if empty)?

Whenever you run a query with `get_terms`, the 'hide_empty' argument is, by default, set to true. That way, let's say you have a page where you list/display the taxonomy's products; whenever the user removes or simply does not have any products within that taxonomy, the taxonomy does not appear or echoes a 'Sorry, there are no available products.' message.

EDIT: In case you would like to have the argument visible, this is how it should look like:

```
<?php get_terms('product_relation', array('hide_empty'=>1)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps i should have explain more. What i want is, there's a custom taxonomy created for every product, so i can relate them to each other. However when a product is deleted, the custom taxonomy still shows in the admin. Over time if a lot of products are deleted the list of custom taxonomies that can be selected will keep growing. The taxonomy is only used to related products, if a product is deleted the taxonomy shouldn't appear any more.

Comment: Please update your answer, using the correct terminology (see edited question). Thanks.

Comment: @Corbula Oh sorry, I actually thought there was a taxonomy holding all of your products. Then you might want to look into this http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12629 - and hook that function to your code.

Comment: @cr0z3r thanks but that seems to be removing custom taxonomies. See the updated question as edited by scribu. I want the terms removed not the taxonomy.